# iOS simulators not working behind proxy since upgraded to Xcode 8.2.1?

Tags: ios, xcode8

I am working in a proxy environment that requires authentication. Since i have upgraded to Xcode 8.2.1, the simulators stop working, however it was working fine with Xcode 8.1 and 7.3 Any help regarding this?

This is the error what i am getting

> PAC Fetch failed with error [NSURLErrorDomain:-1022] []
>   nw_proxy_resolver_create_parsed_array PAC evaluation error:
>   NSURLErrorDomain: -1022

Comment: This issue happens only in 10.2 simulator. Other simulators in Xcode 8.2.1 does not have this issue

Answer (score 26):

The simulator uses your computers network connection, so I recommend checking the System Preferences > Network > Advanced > Proxies > Automatic Proxy Configuration : You must disable Automatic conf.

Comment: Sure we can do that, the issue is we need proxy for other services

Comment: Thanks, after disabling my proxies it worked out for me.

Comment: I'm having a similar problem but when I went to check if my proxy settings the `Automatic Proxy Configuration` was already turned off. Is there anything else you can recommend?

Comment: I can not disable it because my Admin does not enable that option. Besides I need proxy for running other services. That is not an ideal solution sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Like @user6307142 had said above, I checked the

> System Preferences > Network > Advanced > Proxies

and had to untick the checkbox for `Auto Proxy Discovery` and apply the settings and checked it out and it worked.