# NSURLErrorDomain: -1003

Tags: swift, alamofire

I am getting an NSURLErrorDomain: -1003 while I am running my application in Xcode. I haven't seen this error on StackOverflow, any clue about this? 
I am using Alamofire 4

```
func fetchAllPosts() {
        Alamofire.request("http://www.somthing.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?categories_exclude=9").responseJSON
            { response in
                if let data = response.data {
                    do {
                        let newPosts = try JSONDecoder().decode(Posts.self, from: data)
                        self.posts = newPosts.items
                        // Success
                        self.fetchAllPostsDidSucceed()           


                        print("number of posts loaded: \(newPosts.items.count)")
                    }
```

> [17655:2080758] [] nw_proxy_resolver_create_parsed_array PAC evaluation error: NSURLErrorDomain: -1003

Comment: Probably related: [iOS Simulators not working proxy since upgraded to Xcode 8.2.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41541385/ios-simulators-not-working-behind-proxy-since-upgraded-to-xcode-8-2-1/41718542)

Comment: Yes I have the settings for the network, still the same error

Comment: Is this iOS or macOS?

Answer (score 4):

-1003 is [`NSURLErrorCannotFindHost`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/1508628-url_loading_system_error_codes/nsurlerrorcannotfindhost?language=objc).

If you ever need to look up a `NSURLError` code in the future, press <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> (the letter “oh”) in Xcode, search for `NSURLError`, unselect the “Swift” toggle in the upper right corner of the search box and choose/open `NSURLError.h`, and you’ll see all the codes that header file.

This particular error can be caused by any of a number of issues. For example, if this is a macOS app, you may want to go to your target settings, click on the “Capabilities” tag and make sure that “Outgoing Connections (Client)” is selected.

[image: capabilities snapshot]